# Check if user saved in SQLite database in Xamarin

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin

I have Xamarin forms app ,the user will register and login for first time and save username in SQLite database ,then I want the app check if the database found and the username is have been inserted any time he open the app.
i used this code in registration page :

```
SqliteUser squser = new SqliteUser()
            {
                appUser = user
            };
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<SqliteUser>();
                int rows = conn.Insert(squser);
            };
```

I checked the user is inserted successfully.
Now I made CheckUserpage to check if there is a user registered, if yes the alert me the name of first user inserted :-

```
 public partial class CheckUserPage : ContentPage
    {
        public CheckUserPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CheckSqlUser();
        }
        private void CheckSqlUser() {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
            {
                var userQuery = conn.Table<SqliteUser>().Where(a=>a.appUser!="");


                if (userQuery != null) {
                    DisplayAlert("user found", "user found", "OK");
                }
            };

        }

    }
```

How can I get the first user name inserted ?
Best Regard

Comment: What is your question?  Do you just want to know how to query the db?  There are official docs and numerous example of how to do this.  If you have a specific question or error about doing this, please provide the details so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

to get the first value in a list, use LINQ

```
using System.Linq;

var userQuery = conn.Table<SqliteUser>().Where(a=>a.appUser!="");
var results = userQuery.ToList();
var first = results.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks alot ,I want to display the result in alert , i have one column called appuser

Comment: use DisplayAlert()